# Solarized color name not defined

Tags: gnome-terminal, vi

I recently installed the Solarized theme for gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 12.04, but now, every time I used vim, I receive the warning "Warning: Color name "S_base03" is not defined". This warning is printed whether or not I am using the solarized colorscheme for vim. Otherwise, everything else seems normal. Any clue why I might be getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this exact problem.  Ubuntu, by default, no longer supports preprocessor directives in `.Xresources`, yet [xresources\solarized](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources/solarized) depends on these directives.

I found two solutions (either one alone works for me).

- Rename `~/.Xresources` to `~/.Xdefaults` and log in again (this is kind of funny because `.Xdefaults` is deprecated).
- Create `.xprofile` with the following content and log in again:

  ```
  SYSRESOURCES=/etc/X11/Xresources
  USRRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources
  ```

You don't have to login again if you just `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with the second solution and it worked perfectly for me as well.